# Overriding bootstrap styles

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a `bootstrap.min.css` and the following div.

```
<div class='jumbotron'> 
</div>
```

I am overriding this class using a custom css file.

```
.jumbotron{
    background: green url(../img/city.jpg) no-repeat top left;
}
```

But the contents of the class `jumbotron` are not changing. I know the css is included properly, because it works for other divs that share no name with bootstrap. 
How do I solve this problem?

Comment: are you calling the custom css file after the bootstrap.min.css in html?

Comment: @13ruce1337 Ofcourse. As I said, other divs are being rendered properly.

Comment: Also check that the image exists on that path from the css file.

Comment: Can you include an example?

Comment: @Adrift There is nothing to include actually. I am working on a clean project. I have fresh Larvel, Bootstrap installed.

Answer (score 2):

Inspect the element in Chrome's developer tools (or Firefox has something similar, don't know what they call it).

`Right click > Inspect Element`

Now look at the CSS styles to the right. Do you see your custom style somewhere in the list? You may have to scroll down a bit.

If it's not in the list, that means your CSS file is not getting included properly or the element name is misspelled, so your styles are not being applied.

If it is in the list but crossed off, that means one of bootstrap's styles is probably overriding it. You can make your styles take precedence over bootstrap's styles by using a [more specific selector](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)

Comment: Actually, I can see my css is included. Because I can see it when I click on it from the developer tools. Other elements that do not contain bootstrap's name are being rendered correctly, from the costume css file

Comment: You can see your styles in the element inspector but reflected not on the page? Try adding something unmissable like `width: 500px; height: 500px; background-color: green` and see if it shows up.

Answer (score 1):

Is your custom CSS file called after the bootstap.min.css. 
Maybe the bootstrap.min.css has more importance:

http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/cascade.html#cascade

Example from above link:

> *             {}  /* a=0 b=0 c=0 d=0 -> specificity = 0,0,0,0 */
>
>   li  {}  /* a=0 b=0 c=0 d=1 -> specificity = 0,0,0,1 */
>
>   li:first-line {}  /* a=0 b=0 c=0 d=2 -> specificity = 0,0,0,2 */
>
>   ul li         {}  /* a=0 b=0 c=0 d=2 -> specificity = 0,0,0,2 */
>
>   ul ol+li      {}  /* a=0 b=0 c=0 d=3 -> specificity = 0,0,0,3 */
>   h1 + *[rel=up]{}  /* a=0 b=0 c=1 d=1 -> specificity = 0,0,1,1 */
>
>   ul ol li.red  {}  /* a=0 b=0 c=1 d=3 -> specificity = 0,0,1,3 */
>
>   li.red.level  {}  /* a=0 b=0 c=2 d=1 -> specificity = 0,0,2,1 */
>
>   #x34y         {}  /* a=0 b=1 c=0 d=0 -> specificity = 0,1,0,0 */
>
>   style=""          /* a=1 b=0 c=0 d=0 -> specificity = 1,0,0,0 */

```
<HEAD>
<STYLE type="text/css">
  #x97z { color: red }
</STYLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<P ID=x97z style="color: green">
</BODY>
```

In the above example, the color of the P element would be green. The declaration in the "style" attribute will override the one in the STYLE element because of cascading rule 3, since it has a higher specificity.

Comment: Nope. It is called `custom.css`

Comment: I diddn't mean called as in what you named it. I meant called as in the order in which is loaded.

Comment: It is called exactly as shown in this example. http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/ in the "Basic Template" section

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `.jumbotron` CSS override follows the bootstrap.min.css in your HTML file.

Demo: http://bootply.com/tbFqSQQcOi

Comment: Nope. I don't think that is it. This is the strangest problem I've faced. I think it might be from caching. I am using Laravel. So, I will check out laravel section